# Why quaternion is defined by [vector,w] why not by [point,w]?

Tags: graphics, vector, rotational-matrices, quaternions

A quaternion rotation defines a point in 3d-space and rotation around the axis of that point. 
I am trying to understand why quaternion rotation requires a vector and rotation, why not just a 3d point in space and rotation ?

eg : In the following picture a hand points to a point in 3d-space which can be rotated around its axis.
http://s29.postimg.org/ih79tirnr/quarternion.jpg

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand the distinction: the vector is defined by a point.

Comment: Vector is a point is 3d-space (also called as direction) and a magnitude while point is just a point in 3d-space(no magnitude).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the x, y and z components of a quaternion define a vector pointing in the direction of the axis of rotation.  The w component defines the amount of the rotation along that axis.  So, the x, y and z don't actually signify a point at all. As the amount of rotation changes, the length of the x, y, z vector will change but the vector always points in the same direction. It doesn't make sense, therefore, to consider this to be a point in space.  It's merely a direction and a rotation around that axis.

I once defined a new class that included a quaternion to define the transformation of an object along with a vector to describe the translation of the object.  The object could then represent a complete transformation in 3D space similar to a 3x4 transformation matrix.

Comment: Thanks David, for  your time and input.
I'll appreciate if you can clarify 2 more questions:
1. As you mentioned that magnitude is the scaling factor, is it the scaling factor of the object to which quaternion value is applied, if that's the case then is it a uniform scaling factor( one value will define scale-x, scale-y and scale-z) or is it the scaling factor of something else ?

Comment: 2. As you also explained that as the amount of rotation changes, the length of the x,y,z vector will change but the vector always points in the same direction. If you meant rotation along the axis will change; doesn't it only affects w-value? How the rotation along the axis will change the length of the vector ?


Thanks again

Comment: Let me correct a mistake in my original post.  The magnitude of the quaternion doesn't have any effect on the transformation.

Since the magnitude of a quaternion is irrelevant, let's assume that we always use a unit quaternion - that is, one where x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 = 1.  In this quaternion, the vector <x, y, z> represents a vector in space scaled by sin(1/2 θ) and w is cos (1/2 θ).

No rotation would correspond to <0, 0, 0, 1>. A 180 degree rotation about the X axis would be <1, 0, 0, 0>. A 90 degree rotation about the Y axis would be <0, 0.7071, 0, 0.7071>.

Comment: Sorry to dredge up an old post, but this is an axis-angle rotation, not a quaternion.  A quaternion is a lot less intuitive.  You can think of x, y, z, and w as proportionally mixing rotations around the x axis, y axis, z axis, and no rotation (w).  So (x:1,y:0,z:0,w:1) is halfway between rotating 180 degrees along the X axis and no rotation at all, so the result is 90 degrees along X.  Also, it needs to be normalized, so (1,0,0,1) should actually be (0.707,0,0,0.707).